# Grid and cards issues with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I almost finish a very important part in my Django project by creating `panels` which contains some `cards`. I'm using `Bootstrap 3 (BS3)` and I integrated cards from `BS4` to `BS3`.

I'm getting an issue and I would like to get your mind because the behaviour is a little bit weird.

**My issue :**

As you can see in the animated picture below, there is an offset when I open dropdown from **Publication n°1** and **Publication n°2**. It creates an offset with cards from the second row.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My question is : How I can rewrite bootstrap part in my code in order to make a normal behaviour ?

**What I would like to get for each card:**

This is what I would like for each card : open the card > make an offset to the entire row below

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**What I have and I don't want as behaviour :**

And don't have a behaviour like that :

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

**My code :**

This is my entire code :

```
{% for category in research_categories|dictsort:'name' %}
  <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion_{{ category.id }}" role="tablist"
       aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{ category.id }}"
             href="#collapseOne_{{ category.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            {{ category }}
            {% for item in category.publication.all %}
              {% if item.new_publication == True %}
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne_{{ category.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"
           aria-labelledby="#accordion_{{ category.id }}">
        <div class="panel panel-default subpanel ">
          <div class="row">
            {% for element in research_publications|dictsort:'pub_id' %}
              {% if element.category|stringformat:"s"  == category|stringformat:"s" %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card" style="width:350px">
                    <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 350px; height: 350px" src="{{ element.cover.url }}" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">{{ element }} - {{ element.pub_id }}
                        {% if element.new_publication == True %}
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                        {% endif %}
                      </h4>

                      <button class="btn btn-default display-document" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                              data-target="#dropdown_{{ element.id }}"
                              aria-expanded="false"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                      <div id="dropdown_{{ element.id }}" class="collapse">
                        <div class="publication-title">
                          <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tbody>

                            {% for item in test_research %}
                              {% if item.publication|stringformat:"s"  == element|stringformat:"s" %}
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="col-md-1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="fakeRadio" name="DocumentChoice"
                                           value="{{ item.code }}">
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="col-md-5 document-title">{{ item.title }}</td>
                                  <td class="col-md-1 document-language"> {{ item.language }}</td>
                                  <td class="col-md-1">
                                    {% if item.format == 'pdf' %}
                                      <img src="{% static 'app/img/pdf-icon.png' %}"
                                           style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if item.format == 'epub' %}
                                      <img src="{% static 'app/img/epub-icon.png' %}"
                                           style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>
                                    {% endif %}
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="col-md-1 document-flag">
                                    {% if item.publication.new_publication == True %}
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                                    {% else %}
                                      <span></span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="col-md-1 document-cover">
                                    {% if item.publication.cover %}
                                      <a href="{{ item.publication.cover.url }}">
                                        <img class="popup_image"
                                             style="width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:2px;"
                                             id="myImg_{{ item.id }}" src="{{ item.publication.cover.url }}">
                                      </a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And this is a simplified version from my previous code in order to try some things :

```
{% for category in research_categories|dictsort:'name' %}
  <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion_{{ category.id }}" role="tablist"
       aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{ category.id }}"
             href="#collapseOne_{{ category.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            {{ category }}
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne_{{ category.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"
           aria-labelledby="#accordion_{{ category.id }}">
        <div class="panel panel-default subpanel ">
          <div class="row">
            {% for element in research_publications|dictsort:'pub_id' %}
              {% if element.category|stringformat:"s"  == category|stringformat:"s" %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card" style="width:350px">
                    <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 350px; height: 350px" src="{{ element.cover.url }}" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">{{ element }}</h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-default display-document" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                              data-target="#dropdown_{{ element.id }}"
                              aria-expanded="false"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                      <div id="dropdown_{{ element.id }}" class="collapse">
                        <div class="publication-title">
                          <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tbody>
                            {% for item in test_research %}
                              {% if item.publication|stringformat:"s"  == element|stringformat:"s" %}
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="col-md-5 document-title">{{ item.title }}</td>
                                </tr>
                              {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know if you need my css part, but I think the issue is maybe due to my bootstrap grid ?

Thank you !

Comment: We can't use your shortcodes etc. We need a **functional** example with the **actual output** HTML & CSS.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What would be the "normal behaviour" for you? To push all the bottom columns together when you click Publication n°1 and Publication n°2 ?

Comment: @Paulie_D With Django, it's not easy to provide a functional example because it doesn't include just CSS and HTML language. I can try to provide a functional example, better than given in my question.

Comment: @Vrle As you can see on my GIF, when I click on Publication n°5 at the beginning, it doesn't shift other cards with a big space. It shifts the line below at the same time. But when I click on Publication n°1 or n°2, it doesn't shift the entire row below, but only separated cards. I will provide in my question a better example to illustrate what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a `clearfix` issue. Can you try adding this to your css:

```
.panel.panel-default.subpanel > .row  > .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

Depending on your other code it might need some more variations for different screen sizes.

Comment: Yes it's someting like this. I have 6 cards. With your CSS, I get 3 rows with 2 cards, then 3 cards, then 1 card and not 2 rows with 3 cards, then 3 cards. Maybe something due to `(3n+3)` ?

Comment: Expanded it a bit so it clears after 3rd md-4 element.

Comment: Your edit gives me exactly the same issue than mine before to ask my question. Before your edit it was good except cards position.

Comment: It's hard not being able to try it. Can you try with `(3n+1)` without the `:after`, `content: "";` and `display: table;` ?

Comment: It's that ! Now I will try to understand why it works now ! Thank you :)

Comment: You can have a play with it here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

The funny part is the `3n+3` looks like a good solution, but it's easier when you can try it hands on.